# How to use Kotlin to generate a javascript function `constructor`?

Tags: javascript, constructor, kotlin, keyword

I want to use Kotlin to generate some JavaScript like following:

```
function MyComponent() {
    self.constructor = function() {}
}
```

The problem is `constructor` is a keyword in Kotlin, I can't just write like:

```
class MyComponent {
  fun constructor() {}
}
```

I also tried:

```
class MyComponent {
    @JsName("constructor")
    fun ctor() {}
}
```

It still report errors like:

```
JavaScript name generated for this declaration clashes 
with built-in declaration {1}
```

How to generate a javascript function which has name `constructor`?

Comment: I know it's not really solving your problem, but maybe just try changing the letter 'c' to uppercase? ... Just a suggestion...

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V The `constructor` name is required by the js lib used with kotlin, can't be changed

Comment: I see your problem, I've never used `kotlin` personally, I've been meaning to, however, I've never actually used it, JS on the other hand... have you tried something like `window["constructor"]` within your JS? I'm not sure if that would work or not...

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V thanks, this is indeed a method worth trying

Comment: No problem at all, I hope it works fine for you. I think it *may* work due tot he way it's been written, I may be wrong, who knows. Let me know if it works or not? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no problem with the top-level functions. The `fun constructor() {}` should just work, yielding `function constructor(){}`. At least that's what it does in Kotlin 1.2.31.

On the other hand member functions named `constructor` are prohibited (e.g. you cannot get `A.prototype.constructor = function () {}` in the output js file). For one thing that would ruin the `is`-check implementation.

Modifying the constructor property inside the class constructor should be possible:

```
// Kotlin
class A {
  init{
    this.asDynamic().constructor = fun(a: Int) { println(a) }
  }
}

// JS
function A() {
  this.constructor = A_init$lambda;
}
function A_init$lambda(a) {
  println(a);
}
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: You say it should just work? - This isn't really useful feedback? I personally don't use Kotlin myself, but as I said, could he not just do something like `window["constructor"]`? Again, I wouldn't know, I know JS, Kotlin, not so much.

Comment: @anton Yes, you are right if `fun constructor` is at top level, thanks! Actually I simplified my problem too hard, my real problem is the `constructor` inside a class. Let me modify the question

Comment: @Freewind It is possible to modify the property inside the class constructor (added to the answer). Is that what you want?

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V I was being polite. No, `window["constructor"]` is not the solution, because a) it solves the problem that doesn't exist, and b) window is not defined in some environments (e.g. NodeJs)

Comment: @Freewind by the way, could you tell what exactly that library uses the constructor property for?

Comment: @AntonBannykh I posted it to <https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-23576>, please tell me if that's not clear enough, thanks!